# Why does Chrome request resources that are not part of my site?

Tags: google-chrome

My site has like 5 files:

1. index.htm
2. favicon.ico
3. picture 1
4. picture 2
5. cache.mf

but I include links (in comments and js) to other sites. When I initially load my page chrome scrapes through all of those links. I don't want it to do that.

Comment: It sounds like you're seeing prefetching. http://www.technipages.com/google-chrome-disable-prefetch.html

Answer (score 0):

It is Google. It probably can't restrain to crawl the web... You probably can't do anything.

Well, you can of course - it is open source. Change it accordingly and recompile.